# Mapping websockets endpoints at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I know we can map a servlet at runtime since servlet api 3.0, that can be achieved as below:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent sce ) {
    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();

    String servletMapping = "/yourURL";
    ServletRegistration sr = sc.addServlet( servletMapping, "org.yourdomain.yourclass" );
    sr.setInitParameter( "key", "value" );
    sr.addMapping( servletMapping );
}
```

Is there a similar way of doing this with websockets (using javax.websockets.api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Websocket equivalent of `ServletContainerInitializer` is the [`ServerApplicationConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerApplicationConfig.html). It only doesn't require a services file, the Websocket API will proactively scan the WAR and JARs in WAR for any classes implementing `ServerApplicationConfig` interface and use them. You can in `getEndpointConfigs()` use [`ServerEndpointConfig.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.html) to programmatically build a Websocket endpoint and return it.

Here's a kickoff example, given that `YourEndpoint.class` represents the Websocket endpoint you'd like to programmatically add, and you'd like to ignore any scanned classes.

```
public class YourServerApplicationConfig implements ServerApplicationConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> scannedClasses) {
        Set<ServerEndpointConfig> configs = new HashSet<>();
        configs.add(ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(YourEndpoint.class, "/yourPath").build());
        return configs;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scannedClasses) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but what I am really after is a way to change endpoints at runtime, for servlets I keep a reference to servlet context and can add servlets anytime during runtime. ServerApllicationConfig  methods gets called at startup only right?

Comment: Adding/removing servlets is not allowed after the context has initialized. It would throw ISE. So, it's not different.

Comment: Ouch... I was counting on being able change mappings after initialization. You're right it does not work. Thanks.